# Checkout Klarna from country other than norway

Tags: php, checkout, klarna

Testing klarna checkout

https://checkout.testdrive.klarna.com/checkout/orders

with the credentials provided by klarna

```
Email address: checkout-no@testdrive.klarna.com
Postal code: 0563
Personal identity number: 01087000571
First name: Testperson-no
Last name: Approved
Address: Sæffleberggate 56
City: Oslo
Phone Number: 40 123 456
```

but it is only for Norway, when someone want to test it from other country it gives error (like on zip code), as it checks against IP. 
Check the error here: 
http://tinypic.com/r/r05h0o/9

- Tried to change my location to germany, added its Zip code but it then give problem on Social Security Number
  Check the error here: 
  http://tinypic.com/r/10pr1io/9

Comment: As this stands it's more suited as a support request for Klarna. Please include the relevant code + raw errors you get from their API. Where exactly is the IP check, etc?

Comment: Please check the image links for errors + It didn't have the raw code it is loaded through iframe or script

Comment: Do you have a link to the Klarna developer documentation page describing how you've implemented this?

Comment: https://developers.klarna.com/en/no+php/kco-v2/checkout/2-embed-the-checkout

Comment: I thinks I have to change my purchase country here
$create['purchase_country'] = 'SE';   // to my country code

Comment: It will not solve my problem